# Почему возникает ошибка «parameter 1 of constructor in required a bean of type that could not be found.»

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

вот сервис
CompanyService

```
package ru.sergalas.perpay.entities.companies.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import ru.sergalas.perpay.entities.companies.mappers.CompanyMapper;
import ru.sergalas.perpay.entities.companies.repository.CompaniesRepository;

@Service
public class CompaniesService {

    private final CompaniesRepository companiesRepository;

    private final CompanyMapper companyMapper;

    public CompaniesService(CompaniesRepository companiesRepository, CompanyMapper mapper)
    {
        this.companiesRepository = companiesRepository;
        this.companyMapper = mapper;
    }
}
```

вот ComapanyMapper

```
package ru.sergalas.perpay.entities.companies.mappers;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import ru.sergalas.perpay.entities.companies.dto.CompanyReadDTO;
import ru.sergalas.perpay.entities.companies.dto.CompanyWriteDTO;
import ru.sergalas.perpay.entities.companies.entity.Companies;
import java.util.UUID;

@Mapper(imports = UUID.class)
public interface CompanyMapper {

    CompanyReadDTO toDTO(Companies companies);

    @Mapping(target="id", source="id", defaultExpression = "java( UUID.randomUUID())")
    Companies toEntity(CompanyWriteDTO dto);
}
```

вот gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.10'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}
apply from: 'version.gradle'

group = 'ru.sergalas'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
  compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
  implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:${versions.gson}"
  implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:${versions.jjwt}"
  implementation "org.json:json:${versions.json}"
  implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:${versions.lombokmapstruct}"
  compileOnly "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${versions.mapstruct}"

  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

  runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
  runtimeOnly "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:${versions.jjwtimpl}"
  runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-orgjson:${versions.jjwtimpl}") {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
  }

  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${versions.mapstructProcessor}"
}

tasks.named('test') {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

при сборке проекта получаю ошибку

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in ru.sergalas.perpay.entities.companies.service.CompaniesService required a bean of type 'ru.sergalas.perpay.entities.companies.mappers.CompanyMapper' that could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все было просто надо было создать конфигурационный файл где прописать эти бины. Пишу для будущих поколений ))).

```
@Configuration
public class MapperBean {

    @Bean
    public UserMapper userMapper() {
        return Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CompanyMapper companyMapper() {
        return Mappers.getMapper(CompanyMapper.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример конфигурационного файла, который решил вашу проблему